# howto hide/show pivot element in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

is it possible to hide and show a pivot element?

e.g. i want a option in my app in which i can show or hide one special pivot item which is not usefull for every user.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it's not possible to hide an entry in the items collection.
The only option available is to remove and add the item from the pivots `Items` collection.

Depending on the application and the design of the pivot it may be appropriate to leave the item always there but give it the header "advanced".

Comment: the problem here is, when i change it to "collapsed" it is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can  remove the pivot item from the parent pivot control

```
parentPivotControl.Items.Remove(pivotItemToBeRemoved);
```